# Temperature dial on shower has stiffened up and no longer moves

Tags: water, shower

I have an electric shower in my bathroom, and noticed the other day that the temperature dial has become too stiff to move - this is the first time this has happened in the two years since I moved into the house.

Normally, it wouldn't really be a problem - I barely ever move the dial, but find myself wanting a cold shower these days with the really hot weather.

I googled what might cause this, and according to a [post on this forum](https://www.plumbersforums.net/threads/stiff-shower-temperature-knob-does-anyone-know-the-cause.120427/), it could be caused by limescale build up... As I live in a hardwater area, I'm guessing this is probably the most likely cause.

Is the best thing to do to take the knob off to try and clean underneath it, or is there a better way to check if limescale is what's causing it & then descale it?

Comment: Think you have the right idea, but I think the problem would be more on the inside, than an easy outside cleaning.  Vinegar is the go to household product to use, usually a soak and rinse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good place to start, it's the easiest. CLR is a good cleaner and works fast. If that doesn't work, then you're looking at disassembling the unit further and cleaning it up as you go along. You might want to get some plumber's grease and lube any "o" rings and moving parts.

Comment: Keeping in mind it is an electric shower, full of sparky bits. I'm honestly surprised temperature is not an *electrical* control.

Comment: Electric showers always have the potential to surprise! (In seriousness, though, this is on an island where the light switch for the bath is either outside the room or on the ceiling on a pullcord because -- wait for it -- electricity!)

Comment: I would suggest turning the power off to the heater before cleaning the thermostat unless you are sure it is not associated with electrical power. Turning it off will not hurt anything.

Comment: [CLR™](https://clrbrands.com/products/CLR-Household) might be a US only product and this is obviously a non-US question (electric shower? Not on this side of the pond!) However, this product class of Calcium, Lime and Rust remover is the go-to if the vinegar [mentioned in a comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/253239/temperature-dial-on-shower-has-stiffened-up-and-no-longer-moves#comment505913_253239) doesn't work.